# How to keep subtitles from imported source

Tags: import

I currently have a video file created with a Contour+ Camera, this records GPS information into the file as two subtitle tracks, however when I attempt to import the file into blender I can see the Video and Audio tracks, but the subtitle tracks are ignored.

Using FFMPEG I get the following details of the file

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'FILE0093.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2016-02-14 15:04:01
  Duration: 00:15:33.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 11369 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 11189 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-02-14 15:04:01
      handler_name    : Ambarella AVC
      encoder         : Ambarella AVC encoder
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-02-14 15:04:01
      handler_name    : Ambarella AAC
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (text / 0x74786574), 5 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-02-14 15:04:01
      handler_name    : Ambarella EXT
    Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (text / 0x74786574), 19 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-02-14 15:04:01
      handler_name    : Ambarella EXT
```

The power of this is obviously when clipping and merging this if I can align the subtitle I will retain the information to enable speed guages etc to be applied later.

Can Blender retain the Subtitles or should I be using something else to edit these videos?

Nick(c)

Comment: Blender doesn't have much support for subtitles. Have a [look at this addon](http://www.blendernation.com/2016/02/04/textsync2d3d-enhanced-subtitling-in-blender/) and [this using animation nodes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5t4modDVBY). You would need to use ffmpeg to extract the subtitles as text to import them into blender.

Comment: Thanks for that, it's a shame that it's not there, and odd that it's not been needed before. Is there any other Video Editing Tool for Linux that does import existing subtitle tracks?

Comment: I know there is openshot, kdenlive and pitivi but I haven't used them to know if they work with subtitles.